# What front-end technology should I follow which is fast, SEO-friendly, and has support available (e.g., ReactJS and Thymeleaf)?

Tags: frontend

What front-end technology should I follow which is fast, SEO-friendly, and has support available (e.g., ReactJS and Thymeleaf)?
help

Answer (score -1):

Check this out https://github.com/Atyantik/react-pwa/. I hope this boluer plate will help you to solve your problem.